# find $ f(x) $and the value of C if we have : $\int_0^x{f(t)dt} = \int_x^1 t^2f(t)dt + \frac{x^{16}}{8} + \frac{x^{18}}{9} + C$

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

While working on some challenging questions I found the following one really interesting. I would be so thankful if anyone could help me on this question.

$f(x)$ is continuous for all x and

$\int_0^x{f(t)dt} = \int_x^1 t^2f(t)dt + \frac{x^{16}}{8} + \frac{x^{18}}{9} + C$

Find $f(x)$ and the value of C

Thank you everyone

Comment: Have you tried using the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When derivating,

\begin{equation*}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=\frac{d}{dx}(-\int_{1}^{x}t^2f(t)dt+\frac{x^{16}}{8}+\frac{x^{18}}{9}+C)
\end{equation*}
and using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=-x^2f(x)+2x^{15}+2x^{17}.
\end{equation*}

Thus
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\frac{2x^{15}+2x^{17}}{1+x^2}.
\end{equation*}

By integration,
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{2t^{15}+2t^{17}}{1+t^2}dt=\frac{x^{16}}{8},
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\int_{x}^{1}t^2f(t)dt=\int_{x}^{1}\frac{2t^{17}+2t^{19}}{1+t^2}dt=\frac{1}{9}-\frac{x^{18}}{9}.
\end{equation*}
So
\begin{equation*}
\frac{x^{16}}{8}=\frac{1}{9}-\frac{x^{18}}{9}+\frac{x^{16}}{8}+\frac{x^{18}}{9}+C \Rightarrow C = -\frac{1}{9}.
\end{equation*}